# I don't understand why this program don't compile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a bot like the "!Remindme" reddit bot and I found this Web Scrapper written in C but I don't understand why it doesn't compile. The compiler throws me this:

```
gcc -o crawler src/crawler.o src/html.o src/http.o src/list.o src/queue.o src/url.o -g -Wall -fPIE -lpthread lib/liburiparser.a 
/usr/bin/ld: src/crawler.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: src/html.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: src/http.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: src/url.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: lib/liburiparser.a(UriNormalizeBase.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: lib/liburiparser.a(UriParse.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: lib/liburiparser.a(UriCommon.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: lib/liburiparser.a(UriIp4.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:20: crawler] Error 1
```

Even with the flag -fPIE it doesn't work and I'm confused why.

**EDIT:** I was trying to compile [this repo](https://github.com/iceman201/Web_Scraper)

Comment: What does it throw when you compile with `-fPIE`?

Comment: This question could use a more descriptive title

Comment: Yes I agree, I didn't explain well what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install `liburiparser` (`liburiparser-dev` on ubuntu), and run the following command:

```
gcc -o crawler src/crawler.c src/html.c src/http.c src/list.c src/queue.c src/url.c -g -Wall -lpthread -luriparser -I./include
```

I suggest you do not use those .o files compiled on other systems, most likely with different CPU architectures.

**Side note**: I found that you are using https://github.com/iceman201/Web_Scraper, and it seems that they don't have a configured .gitignore to ignore these .o files which are the source of confusion here.

Answer (score 2):

You are not compiling you are linking. The **linker** `/usr/bin/ld` is talking about that some of the objects files (both direct and from the archive) have to be compiled previously with the `-fPIE` to work.